# Algorithm to compute centraliser

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, computational-algebra

**Given :** $ G = \langle F \rangle \le S_n$ and $h \in G$

**Find :**  $C_G(h) = \langle C \rangle$

**Brute Force Algorithm :**

1. Genrate all elements of $ \sigma \in G$
2. Check $\sigma h = h \sigma$
3. if above condition is satisfied then  $K = K \cup\sigma$
4. $S = \langle K \rangle$

**Algorithm :**

1. For all $\sigma \in F$
2. Check $\sigma h = h \sigma$
3. if above condition is satisfied then  $S = S \cup\sigma$

**Question 1:** Is $S$  a generating set of $C_G(h)$? How to prove it?

**Question 2 :** Is there any better algorithm than above ones?

Comment: Does $\langle G \rangle$ mean the subgroup generated by $G$, or some generating set of $G$? (I would expect the former, but your phrasing suggests the latter). If you do use it to mean a generating set for $G$, I don't think that algorithm works: A generating set for a group may not include anything that commutes with a given $h$, in which case, it seems like the set $S$ will stay empty.

Comment: Your notation is crazy - you should sort that out first. The standard notation is $\langle X \rangle$ denotes the group generated by the set $X$.

Comment: @ Derek Holt I have edited the question

Comment: In the brute force algorithm $C=S=K$ since you are testing all elements of $G$.

Answer (score 0):

The second algorithm doesn't work in $S_3$ for $h=(123)$ and $F=\{(12), (13)\}$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Give an efficient algorithm to compute centralizer

Comment: Efficient, that's for you to determine. However, if you could select your set $F$ to be a set of generators for all the subgroups of $G$ of prime order, one for each subgroup, then the second approach would work. In particular $F$ would have to include all elements of order $2$. This may not be efficient for one $h$ but the same $F$ would work for all $h$.